# Android - Get Images from url as JSON and display them in Gallery view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I need to get some images located on a url using JSON and then show them in Gallery view. Are there any examples or at least could someone describe me the exact steps?

thx

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a web request
2. Grab the JSON response and parse it
3. Load the Images using their URL

Use this library to load images into your Gallery View: **[Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example that can give you complete demo as you need.

[Read this and Learn it.](http://code.google.com/p/molokoloco-coding-project/wiki/AndroidJsonList)

Steps are the same given to you by Mr. Paresh Mayani.